# Is there a way to send html id attribute to a function?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My code is below.I want to send id=content to the function mr. And then write result to the passed  id=result.Although it is only for this html file,I want to make this function available for another html pages, and want to add this function in another util.js file.

```
Add Item:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="content">
        <br>
        <button onclick="javascript:mr('POST',content,result,'post.php');"     
type="button"      

id="btn1">
            Submit
        </button>
<br>
        <button onclick="javascript:mr('GET',content,result,'get.php');" type="button"    

id="btn2" >
            List Jobs
        </button>
        <div id="result"></div>
```

The function  mr is like this.It is for ajax post and get operations:

```
function mr(type,content,result,URL) {

            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();


            //var content = document.getElementById("content").value;
            var vars = "content=" +content;

            if (type == 'GET')
                URL = URL + '?' + vars;


            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                    var return_data = hr.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = return_data;
                }

            }

            hr.open(type, URL, true);


            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            switch(type) {
                case 'GET':
                    hr.send();
                    break;
                case 'POST':
                     hr.send(vars);
                    break;
            }

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Processing...";

        }
    </script>
```

post.php

```
<?php echo "POST\n"; if(isset($_POST)) print_r($_POST); ?>
```

get.php

```
<?php echo "GET\n"; if(isset($_GET)) print_r($_GET); ?>
```

When I click submit ,I got the following output.

```
POST Array ( [content] => [object HTMLInputElement] )
```

And clicking  list button the output:

```
GET Array ( [content] => [object HTMLInputElement] )
```

Comment: What do you want to send? The ID or the content? You seem to be suggesting both. Or maybe I'm misreading it.

Comment: There's no need for "javascript:" in "onclick" attribute values.

Comment: @thesystem I want to send value.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line:

```
var vars = "content=" +content;
```

You're sending the actual `<input>` element instead of it's value or id.  You were on the right track with the commented out line above it.

To send the value, not the input object:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var vars = "content=" + content.value;
```

To send the id:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var vars = "content=" + content.id;
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean.I must include var vars = "content=" +content; to send the content value to php file.

Comment: Yes, but with the line above it commented out `content` refers the the actual input object, not it's value.